# How to increment a field inside the array of documents in mongo Db?

Tags: mongodb

I want to increment the quantity field inside the products array of the cart when the productId matches to the itemid. Also I want to get the updated document in return.

Here is my Cart Model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    products: [
        {
            productId: {
                type: String,
            },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                default: 1
            }
        }

    ]
    
}, {timestamps: true});
const Cart = new mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);

export default Cart;
```

and here is what I m doing:

```
const updatedCart = await Cart.findOneAndUpdate({"products.productId": itemid}, {$inc: {quantity: 1}}, {new: true})

//console.log(updatedCart)
```

But an empty array return and also quantity didn't increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from your schema, there is no `quantity` field. Hence your *mongoose operation* is not updating any document.

Hence it will not return any document as `new: true` only returns the updated document.

> `[options.returnOriginal=null]` «Boolean» An alias for the new option. `returnOriginal: false` is equivalent to `new: true`.

---

You can use [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update the `quantity` of filtered `product` in `products` array.

> The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

```
const updatedCart = await Cart.findOneAndUpdate({ "products.productId": itemid },
  { $inc: { "products.$.quantity": 1 } }, 
  { new: true });
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9Ax7hDdVjhY)